# Desktop effects like Compiz for MacOS

Tags: macos, desktop, desktop-customization, compiz, desktop-effects

Is there a possibility in MacOs to add desktop effects? Like screen raining or a wall of fire which eats a window when you click "minimize".

Example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4QokOwvPxrE

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/608822/how-to-install-compiz-effects-on-gnome-3

Comment: @Steven So that's a "no"?

Comment: @Xen2050: Oh man... I wrote "Gnome" instead of "MacOS".